How to fix URL of My IP going to an account on my server
I have a multiple-domain virtual hosting (I think/assume) on a WHM server set up with a pair of IP addresses as primary and secondary addreses. If I have the primary IP address in my browser (eg https://123.456.567.789/ ) it goes to one of my websites on the server.
If I use the secondary IP address, it works fine and redirects to the WHM default holding page ( https://213.171.204.243/cgi-sys/defaultwebpage.cgi ).
DNS details:
My DNS for the account that is occurring when the IP is put into the address bar is the same for every account on the server, and looks like this:
$TTL 14400
subdomain.mdomain.co.uk.    86400   IN  SOA ns1.server.co.uk.   control.server.co.uk.   (
                        2024051403 ;Serial Number
                        3600 ;refresh
                        1800 ;retry
                        1209600 ;expire
                        86400   )
subdomain.mdomain.co.uk.    86400   IN  NS  ns1.server.co.uk.
subdomain.mdomain.co.uk.    86400   IN  NS  ns2.server.co.uk.
subdomain.mdomain.co.uk.    14400   IN  A   123.456.567.789
subdomain.mdomain.co.uk.    14400   IN  MX  0   subdomain.mdomain.co.uk.
www 14400   IN  CNAME   subdomain.mdomain.co.uk.
_dmarc  14400   IN  TXT "..."
;; PTR record data. Works.
789.567.456.in-addr.arpa.   14400   IN  TXT ns1.live-servers.net.
789.567.456.in-addr.arpa.   14400   IN  TXT root.live-servers.net.
789.567.456.in-addr.arpa.   14400   IN  PTR aerom.mhcreations.co.uk.
;; End PTR record data.
subdomain.mdomain.co.uk.    14400   IN  TXT "v=spf1 +a +mx +ip4:... ~all"
default._domainkey  14400   IN  TXT "..."

Questions

How do I stop people accessing a specific account by using the IP URL?

If I can't stop (1) entirely, how do I set which account is shown to the browser?

Ideally how can I set the IP address URL does what the second IP address URL does and redirects to the cgi-sys/defaultwebpage.cgi ?



I fixed it by Using This Answer and adding an Htaccess redirect for when the domain host names do not match. Not perfect but it works.
More efficient suggestions to do this more centrally are still welcomed.
